# How to create DirectX12 COM objects in C++ and use it in C# to initialize objects in Silk.NET

Tags: c#, c++, directx

I use a nuget package called Silk.NET to use DirectX12 in C#. For example, I can create an IDXGIFactory5 with the following code:

```
var dxgi = DXGI.GetApi();
var d3d12 = D3D12.GetApi();
var factoryFlags = 0u;
var factoryiid = IDXGIFactory5.Guid;
IDXGIFactory5* factory = null;
dxgi.CreateDXGIFactory2(factoryFlags, ref factoryiid, (void**)&factory);
```

But for some unavoidable reasons, I have to create the IDXGIFactory5 COM interface in C++:

```
ComPtr<IDXGIFactory5> factory;
CreateDXGIFactory2(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&factory));
```

How can I convert the COM interface created in C++ to the type in Silk.NET?

(Because I am not good at English, I am using Google Translate to ask questions, please forgive me)

Comment: Are you creating the DXGI factory in `C++` or `C++/CLI`? If it is `C++` can you use `C++/CLI` at all?

Comment: I created the DXGI factory in C++/CX and must use C++/CX

Comment: Just use the constructor with the pointer to the vtable (the ref you got from C/C++): `new IDXGIFactory5(lpvtbl);`

Comment: Oh i see, thanks！

Comment: Sorry, I found that if I want to use lpvtbl I have to add "#define CINTERFACE", but then I cannot call CreateDXGIFactory2 in the original way. How can I modify it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by all that. If you use silk nuget, everything works as expected.

Comment: I mean, how can I get lpvtbl from the cpp code?

Comment: factory.GetAddressOf() => lpvtbl